# Switching to angular-ui-router results in 500 error on $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scala, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an application that uses Angular on the frontend and Scala on the backend.

Originally, the app was using Angular's default `$routeProvider`.

Upon trying to switch to `angular-ui-router` however, `$http.get` and `$http.post` no longer work (I assume `$http` is entirely broken) while client-side routing still works as expected (views and controllers are loaded correctly).

Here are my routes, using `$routeProvider`:

```
$routeProvider
.when(
  "/Home", {
    templateUrl: "app/components/home/home.html",
    controller: "HomeController"
  }
)
.when(
  "/Project/:projectId/ActivityReport", {
    templateUrl: "app/components/activity-report/activityReport.html",
    controller: "ActivityReportController"
  }
)
.when(
  "/Project/:projectId/ActivityReport/:id/print", {
    templateUrl: "app/components/activity-report/activityReportPrint.html",
    controller: "ActivityReportController"
  }
)
.when(
  "/Project/:projectId/ActivityReport/:id", {
    templateUrl: "app/components/activity-report/activityReport.html",
    controller: "ActivityReportController"
  }
)
.when(
  "/ProjectOverview", {
    templateUrl: "app/components/project/project.html",
    controller: "ProjectController"
  }
)
.when(
  "/Login", {
    templateUrl: "views/login.html"
  }
)
.when(
  "/404", {
    templateUrl: "app/shared/404.html"
  }
)
.when(
  "", {
    redirectTo: '/Home'
  }
)
.otherwise({redirectTo: 'Home'});

// use the HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

And using `$stateProvider` (please assume the `templateUrl`'s are the same, there was a major restructure meanwhile):

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController'
})
.state('activity-report', {
  url: '/Project/:projectId/ActivityReport/:id',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/activity-report/activityReport.html',
  controller: 'HomeController'
})
.state('activity-report-print', {
  url: '/Project/:projectId/ActivityReport/:id/print',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/activity-report/activityReportPrint.html',
  controller: 'ActivityReportController'
})
.state('activity-report-new', {
  url: '/Project/:projectId/ActivityReport/',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/activity-report/activityReport.html',
  controller: 'HomeController'
})
.state('project', {
  url: '/ProjectOverview',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/project/project.html',
  controller: 'ProjectController'
})
.state('login', {
  url: '/Login',
  templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
})
.state('404', {
  url: '/404',
  templateUrl: 'app/shared/404.html'
})

// use the HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

Here is the factory that should `get` and `post` the data, which breaks entirely (500 server error) upon switching to `ui-router`:

```
angular.module('bananas').factory("activityReportFactory", ['$http', 'cacheFactory', function ($http, cacheFactory) {

    var urlBase = '/activity';
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.getActivityReport = function(id){
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/' + id);
    };

    dataFactory.saveActivityReport = function(activityReport){
        cacheFactory.remove(urlBase);
        cacheFactory.remove(urlBase + 'project/' + activityReport.projectId + '/activities');
        cacheFactory.remove(urlBase + '/' + activityReport.id);


        return $http.post(urlBase, activityReport);
    };

    dataFactory.cancel = function(activityReport){
        cacheFactory.remove(urlBase);
        cacheFactory.remove(urlBase + 'project/' + activityReport.projectId + '/activities');
        cacheFactory.remove(urlBase + '/' + activityReport.id);

        return $http.delete(urlBase + '/' + activityReport.id);
    };

    return dataFactory;
}]);
```

The exact error message: `POST http://localhost:9000/activity 500 (Internal Server Error)`

And finally, the server logs: http://pastebin.com/iiJmAnaW

What could be breaking the application upon switching to `ui-router`? Everything else remains the same.

EDIT: Here are the response and request headers, as requested: http://pastebin.com/rYLtVVxY

Comment: any error in the console ??

Comment: @swapnesh Yes, the one I mentioned: POST http://localhost:9000/activity 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: can you check the POST request and response in browser console ?

Comment: Also for the time being can you please comment out the following code as few things from your available code is yet not clear to me - $locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});

Comment: @swapnesh Sure, http://pastebin.com/ttxK7cgT here you go.

Comment: the server logs clearly show `ValidationError(error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())`, I doubt this has anything to do with the state provider.

Comment: @Claies Yes, you are correct, yet the request payload validates successfully on JSONLint. What else could be the cause of this ValidationError?

Comment: @Tiago pastebin is showing nothing about the data you are posting

Comment: @swapnesh Updated: http://pastebin.com/rYLtVVxY

Comment: @swapnesh I didn't include it because it validates correctly.

Comment: @Tiago yeah I checked it on Lint too..now check if datatypes are similar, means expected is Int and you are providing Int/boolean

Comment: more specifically here -     "startDateFormatted": "Invalid date",
    "startTimeFormatted": "Invali: d te",
    "endDateFormatted": "Invalid date",
    "endTimeFormatted": "Invali: d te"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84716/discussion-between-swapnesh-and-tiago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per discussion on your switch to `ui-router`, inspect your current controller signature...

```
angular.module('MELon').controller('ActivityReportController', 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$route', '$routeParams', 
    [...]
```

You're likely using `$route` and `$routeParams` in some way, perhaps collecting a value to later use in a `$http` call. Let's switch to ui-router's equivalents - `$state` and `$stateParams`...

```
angular.module('MELon').controller('ActivityReportController', 
    ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', 
    [...]
```

See [$stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateparams-1) and [$state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#state-1) for usage